# c# Find Out Which Method or Class or Object Creates so many threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an server application that needs to run 24x7. The clients connecting to the server hang-up after a few days. We just learned that the server (through the memory dump) generated 800+ threads! On some situations, it would reach to 100+! I know this is really so much and must 'probably' be the cause of calls from the clients not getting serviced.

```
0:000> !threads -live
ThreadCount:      809
UnstartedThread:  790
BackgroundThread: 14
PendingThread:    790
DeadThread:       1
Hosted Runtime:   no
                                   PreEmptive   GC Alloc                Lock
       ID  OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC           Context       Domain   Count APT Exception
   0    1   d4c 012be0a0   2006020 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 STA
   2    2   d54 012c9dd0      b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 MTA (Finalizer)
   3    3   d60 0131a0c0   100a220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
   4    4   d64 01331ef0      b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 MTA
   6    6   d70 01337348   1000220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
   7    7   d8c 0133f100   2000220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 Ukn
   9    a   f90 06c2c948   2000220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 Ukn
  10    b   9a8 06c33f48   200b020 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 MTA
  11    c   584 06c34450   200b020 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 MTA
  12    d   5f4 06c35758   200b020 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 MTA
  13   12   970 06ca6d08   2000220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 Ukn
  14    e  1254 06ca8b38   2000220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 Ukn
  15   13  12f0 06ca9548   2000220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 Ukn
  16    5  10ec 06ca7210   2000220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 Ukn
  17    f  1d90 06cac290   a009220 Enabled  259e45ac:259e4fe8 012b7310     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)
  19   19  1124 06ca7718   8009220 Enabled  258f90c4:258fafe8 012b7310     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)
  20    8  1394 06ca9040   2000220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 Ukn
  22  322  21d4 13698f50   2000220 Enabled  259e6394:259e6fe8 012b7310     0 Ukn
```

The server codes is composed of thousands of lines of codes. Is there an easy tool to check which object generated that much thread?

Comment: A profiler is what you need.

Comment: Try a profiler - I have had good results with the redgate one - http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/